# Drag and Drop sorting with django and ajax

Tags: django, ajax

I want to add drag and drop functionality to the players field. I want to know what are the conditions and requirements for this kind of scenario. What are the steps should I follow? For now, players are stored as we select them (so first selected goes first). I also want to save the order after drag and drop, any suggestions or question improvements will be a great support.

Models.py

```
class Group(TimeStampModel, PermissionsMixin):
name = models.CharField(_("Group name"), blank=False, max_length=127, unique=False)
phase = models.ForeignKey("Phase", related_name="groups", on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=False, null=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ["name"]
```

Forms.py: I'm using modelMultipleChoiceField for now.

```
class GroupCreateForm(ModelForm):
    players = ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=None, help_text=_("Please hold down 'Control', to select more than one player"))
    
        def save(self, commit=True):
            group = super(GroupCreateForm, self).save(False)
        group.phase = self.instance.phase
        group.created_by = get_request().user
        if commit:
            group.save()
        if self.instance:
            for player_id in self.cleaned_data['players']:
                player = Player.objects.get(pk=player_id)
                ranking = GroupRanking(order=0, player=player, group=group)
                ranking.save()

        # Trigger a compute on saving
        group.phase.ruleset.computeScores()

        return group

    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ("name",)
```

views.py

```
class GroupCreateView(AccessControlMixin, CreateView):
model = Group
form_class = GroupCreateForm
template_name_suffix = '_create'

def has_access(self, user):
    return self.can("   ", self.phase.tournament)

def get_success_url(self):
    return "%s" % reverse("tournaments:detail",
                          kwargs={"pk": self.kwargs['pk']})

def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.phase = get_object_or_404(Phase, pk=kwargs['rpk'])
    return super(GroupCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(GroupCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    self.phase = get_object_or_404(Phase, pk=self.kwargs['rpk'])
    self.tournament = get_object_or_404(Tournament, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
    context['phase'] = self.phase
    context['group_size'] = self.phase.group_size
    context['tournament'] = self.tournament
    return context

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.phase = self.phase
    return super(GroupCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
    form = super(GroupCreateView, self).get_form(*args, **kwargs)
    if get_request().user.name_format == 'First name Last name':
        form.fields['players'].queryset = self.phase.not_in_group_players.order_by("first_name", "last_name")
    else:
        form.fields['players'].queryset = self.phase.not_in_group_players.order_by("last_name", "first_name")
    return form


group_create_view = GroupCreateView.as_view()
```

form.py : here is how i'm getting form.palyers.

```
{{ form.name }} and {{ form.players }}
```

This is the working current Output:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG9Ny.png)